# how to save a map section in Python using folium

Tags: python, openstreetmap, folium

I am using folium to generate a map.

```
m = folium.Map(
    location=[47.842167, -120.101655],
    zoom_start=8,
    tiles='Stamen Toner'
)
points = (47.842167, -120.101655), (46.835627, -118.26239)
folium.Rectangle(bounds=points, color='#ff7800', fill=True, fill_color='#ffff00', fill_opacity=0.2).add_to(m)

m
```

I would like to save just the part that is in the rectangle..

[image: The part of the map I would like to save]

Is it possible to do that with python ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: As in save it as an image?

Comment: yes @BobHaffner , but if possible also in html. But only the part in the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of disabling pan and zoom features and also using folium's fit_bounds() you could do something like this.  I think this comes close to your goal

Note: if you don't want to "lock down" the exported file, you can omit the last 3 params in Map()  i.e. `zoom_control`, `scrollWheelZoom` and `dragging`

```
m = folium.Map(
                location=[47.842167, -120.101655],
                zoom_start=8,
                tiles='Stamen Toner',
                zoom_control=False,
                scrollWheelZoom=False,
                dragging=False
              )

sw = [46.835627, -120.101655]
ne = [47.842167, -118.26239]

m.fit_bounds([sw, ne]) 

m.save('mymap.html')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @BobHaffner for you answer. I needed something like that. But it looks like it does not well fit the map. ```m=folium.Map(width=700,height=700,zoom_control=False,scrollWheelZoom=False,dragging=False) points = (46.835627, -120.101655), (47.842167, -118.26239)
folium.Rectangle(bounds=points, color='#ff7800', fill=True, fill_color='#ffff00').add_to(m)
sw = [46.835627, -120.101655]
ne = [47.842167, -118.26239]
m.fit_bounds([sw, ne])
m.save('mymap.html')
m``` It still adds some area around the rectangle. I have displayed the rectangle on the map for better visualization.

Comment: Yeah, i see what you mean.  Maybe fit_bounds() builds in some padding?  Not sure on that.